# Wordpress - Is that possible to calculate a meta's value and sort based on the resulting value?

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I am trying to sort my custom post type in wordpress while using `WP_Query`. Let's say there is a custom field called **`angle`** ( 45, 90, 120, 180,.. etc ). I could sort the values directly. But in this case, I have to sort it based on `sine` or `cosine` of their values. Is there any way I could do that? I am a noob to wordpress and so can't figure this out. This is what I tried, but it didn't work for me.

```
$paged  = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$angles = array( 60, 90, 120 );
$args   =   array(
        "post_type"         =>  "tables",
        "posts_per_page"    =>  15,
        "paged"             =>  $paged,
        "meta_query"        =>  array(
            array(
                    'key'     => 'angle',
                    'value'   => sin(deg2rad($angles)),
                    'compare' => 'IN',
                    'type'    => 
            )       
        )   
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I will try to get you on the right path:

Once you get your WP_Query arguments set up, use this filter:

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'sin_posts_orderby');
```

This function contains MySQL SQL, MySQL functions will work in ORDER BY clauses:

```
function sin_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {
    $orderby_statement = " SIN(angle) ASC ";
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

Run your query:

```
$sin_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Remove the filter:

```
remove_filter('posts_orderby', 'sin_posts_orderby');
```

This is how I would approach it, you will probably need to figure out what query you are running with WP_Query, I believe it is contained in the object.